# org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException - While accessing model by a web service (Jax-ws)

Tags: hibernate, jax-ws

Firstly, I have searched for a solution to this in many questions and thread but none was able to answer it that get it resolved, that is why I am asking it.

Problem is that, I have a model having 2 `List` which are declared to be `Lazy` loaded because they are heavy and I do not want them to be loaded each time `product` is loaded. E.g, in the code below both mapping lists are lazy loaded.

```
class Product{
     Integer id;
     List<CategoryMapping> categoryMappings;
     List<BrandMapping> brandMappings;
}
```

Suppose I have a method in webservice named `getAllProducts()` whose sole responsibility is to return a `List<Product>` without any further dependencies;

I perfectly fetch a list using Hibernate but when it comes to returning the list to client, then this error pops out:

```
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: myproj.model.catalog.Product.brandMappings, could not initialize proxy - no Session
```

Is there any way by which I can make webservice method to ignore lazy loading methods and let the list get returned to the client.

And yes as note, I am using Sping, Hibernate and glassfish (latest stable versions of all these) and all classes are annotation driven

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make another class without lists and expose this class on the service.

Comment: You mean I should load data in the list before sending to the client?

Comment: But suppose I have 5000 products, then I would require to call these two lists in each of 5000 products, which is eventually not going to be get used. Isn't there any way I can send blank list to the client or web-service just ignore these lists.

Comment: Is this the only way? Seems like not many people face this issue that hibernate hasn't done anything for it.

Comment: If you send an empty list, the client will think the product received has no categoryMappings. So, you don't want to send an empty list, but no list at all. This is not a Hibernate problem, it's an API design problem.